# Template error: Method "siteUrl" for object "Craft\ConfigVariable" does not exist

Tags: localization, multi-environment

Method "siteUrl" for object "Craft\ConfigVariable" does not exist

```
{% for locale in otherLocales %}

    {# Is this an entry page? #}
       {% if entry is defined %}

         {# Find the current entry in the other locale #}
        {% set localeEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(locale).first %}

        {# Make sure that it's actually localized to this locale #}
       {% if localeEntry.locale == locale %}

           {# Output a link to it #}
            <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ locale }}" href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] ~ (localeEntry.uri != '__home__' ? localeEntry.uri) }}">
         {% endif %}

    {% else %}

        {# Just output the same path with the locale's base URL #}
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ locale }}" href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] ~ craft.request.getPath() }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please add more information to your question... specifically, code from config file showing how "siteUrl" is set...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you [configure siteUrl](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/localization) in `general.php`?

```
return array(
    // ...
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en' => 'http://example.com/en/',
        'de' => 'http://example.com/de/',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Yes. Also in the index.php. I use a multi-environment config file and the site is multi-language.

Comment: @JohannesLamers Can you share what the relevant part of your multi-environment config looks like?